# Instantiating a view controller with identifier in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Normally I would've done the following to create a view controller and set its `dataSource` using *Objective-C*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Now I would like to convert it to *Swift*. This is my attempt so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    var startingViewController = PageContentViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    var viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController];
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, animated: 0, completion: nil)

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

I'm not sure why it's throwing an error for:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, animated: 0, completion: nil)
```

**Error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the `direction:` parameter is `UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection`, therefore the argument must be one of the possible values, e.g. `UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward` (which can be shortened to `.Forward`
due to the automatic type inference).

And the type of the `animated:` parameter is `Bool`, therefore the argument must
be `true` or `false`, and not `0`.

Together:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```